# Rust: как сделать кликабельные пути к файлу в стандартном выводе по результату работы ".exe" (windows)

Tags: вывод, rust

Имеется цикл перебора в файловой системе (на Windows), и я хотел бы выводить в стандартный вывод ссылки на отдельные файлы, щелкнув по которым можно сразу открыть файл. На данный момент мои ссылки просто обычный текст, и я ищу способ это улучшить.

Comment: Никак, если терминал не поддерживает это.

Comment: Это должен террминал поддерживать, и тогда, по идее, оно автоматически определяет, что текст явяляется ссылкой, и будет кликабельным.

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь PowerShell (7.2.5) как терминалом для запуска консольных приложений и там все ссылки кликабельны. Для файлов нужно выводить URL в формате: `file:///C:/Users/user/Pictures/image.jpg`

Comment: казалось бы: и при чём тут программа powershell?

Comment: PowerShell это терминал стандартного вывода для Windows. Я им исключительно пользуюсь для программирования на Rust. Вывод `println!()` из Rust, если он содержит ссылки, автоматически кликабелен.

Comment: К сожалению, я не смогу обеспечить PowerShel на каждой машине, которая использует мою программу (программа в продакшене), такое решение, увы, не подойдет. Спасибо вам за ваш комментарий!